# Efficiently building a dictionary from many DFs (>20gb in total)

Tags: performance, pandas, dictionary

I have roughly 25gb stored across thousands of .parquet files. They look like this:

```
ID  |  Value
```

Each ID itself is unique, however, there can be multiple entries for one ID (with same and different values).

I would like to:

1. Read in the .parquet files efficiently (parallel processing) and convert each to a pandas data frame.
2. Remove duplicate ID-Value pairs in each data frame (I am only interested in unique pairs) to downsize as soon as possible.
3. **Build a common representation over ALL .parquet files/data frames that is a dictionary of ID:[Values].**
4. Merge the dictionary by Values with another dictionary where the values are keys.

Essentially, I have all this up to (including) step 3 implemented. However, the building of the dictionary currently takes too long as I am iterating over each data frame:

Parameter 'df' is result of step 1, i.e. the converted .parquet file. The function is part of a class (that's why there are *self*) and is called inside another function, which is executed using multiprocessing and 8 cores. The dictionary is itself is a member variable (shared object) of the class and is built iteratively.

```
def build_id_map(self, df):
    df = df.drop_duplicates()

    def check_existence(row):
        if row['id'] not in self.id_dict:
            self.id_dict[row['id']] = [row['value']]
        else:
            if row['id'] not in self.id_dict[row['id']]:
                self.id_dict[row['id']].append(row['value'])

    df.apply(check_existence, axis=1)
```

I am looking for a considerably more efficient solution to the building this dictionary as, currently, it takes roughly 15 seconds for 1 file, which is too much for the large number of files.

Furthermore, I am happy to hear ideas on how to realize point 4 efficiently.

Comment: As a first step you can call `drop_duplicates()` on each df, rather than looping

Comment: The code above is calling drop_duplicates() on each df. The looping happens through df.apply using check_existence() on each row.

Comment: OK, didn't see that, rather than looping to check the row you can also filter the other df by doing `df[~df['ID'].isin(other_df)]` so you only take the rows that are not already in df if you understand

Comment: Thanks, this gave me an idea! I now switched to building a DF instead of a Dict. Memory consumption is reasonable as there are so many duplicates and its' ~20 times faster. Also, I am removing duplicates only every 200 files  as this causes significant overhead otherwise.
However, I had to drop the multiprocessing so far as I didn't get it working with the DF. Maybe I will get it working again and see if it helps.

Further ideas appreciated as its still rather slow!

Comment: If you are using multiprocessing and trying to return a Dataframe, that is going to be slow because it must be serialized to generic objects before being pushed to another process. Either write the df out to disk (see to_hdf or to_feather) or do as much reduction in the worker threads as feasible before aggregating to a single result.

Comment: Yes, I also read that. I eventually decided to perform the duplicate filtering on Spark, which sized the data down to roughly 400mb, making it all handy to operate with locally. Thanks for the input!